# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized when requesting RestApi data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am triyng to get data from the Rest API. API wants 3 things to give authentication;

first one is "Accept:application/vnd.###.v1.0+json"

second one : "Content Type : application/json"

third one : Base64 encoded "userName:password" string

and I should pass these credentials for validation and authorization in custom header.I know there are a lot of thread on this site about this topic but I couldn't solve the problem from them.

Here is the code block :

```
 public class McAfeeIPSManager
{
    String URL = "https://serviceOfApi/sdkapi/session";

    public void getWebRequest()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password1";


        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Accept = "application/vnd.###.v2.0+json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";


        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic "+encoded);



        try
        {
            // Get response  
            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string responseBody = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                    // Console application output  
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Response Body ---> " + responseBody);
                    //Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }

           }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

How can get data from WebAPI under these conditions?Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have no `PreAuthenticate` and `Credentials`? I have a code that may help you:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
    .Create("https://pwmaffr2:8443/remote/system.delete?names=" + DeviceName + "");
request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "Basic YTph");
request.ContentType = "text/html";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string X = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: preAuthenticate parameter not solved my problem.I have examined your code , network credentials might be added to my code but the format will base64 encoding.

Comment: have you build credential like i did? request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

Comment: yes ı did but as I said username password should be base64 encoded

Answer (score 0):

hmm in addition of what i post try deal with this it should work for you hope:

```
string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
string authorization = String.Concat("basic ", base64);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
```

Comment: there is no difference between what I did in the code.

Comment: i don't get it i use McAfee API too

Comment: can you get the session info? I did't do anything different what I wrote

Comment: The production code is for epo McAfee but it can't be much difference for authentification.